# How do I switch between 2 inherited classes in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a display class that inherits from a print class for its function overloads

```
class Print {
    virtual size_t write(uint8_t) = 0;
    void write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) {
      while (size--) {
        write(*buffer++);
      }
    }
   //other print functions (e.g. println())
}

class display : public Print {
  public:
    uint8_t _displayBuffer[512];
    //other display variables
    void update() {
       //write buffer to screen
    }
    size_t write(uint8_t char) {
       //print to buffer
    }
}
```

But I also wanted a feature to display directly to the screen (with limitations), and one way to do that would be to make a new class like so

```
class displayDirect : public Print {
  public:
    //display variables
    void update() {
       //do nothing
    }
    size_t write(uint8_t char) {
       //print to screen
    }
}
```

But sometimes the limitations of the direct printing functions are not desired, and I want to switch between them, so in a very desperate attempt I just copied all the print functions for the direct printing

```
class display : public Print {
  public:
    uint8_t _displayBuffer[512];
    //other display variables
    void update() {
       //write buffer to screen
    }
    size_t write(uint8_t char) {
       //print to buffer
    }

    size_t writeDirect(uint8_t char) {
       //print to screen
    }
    void writeDirect(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) {
      while (size--) {
        writeDirect(*buffer++);
      }
    }
    //all the other print functions
}
```

This way, I could use the screen buffer to do other stuff while I use the printDirect() function instead, then switch back when I am done using the memory.

I had to copy and rename many of the print() functions inside the print class to printDirect(). I feel that there must is a better way to do this.

I do not want to create both classes because then there would be a duplicate of the display variables that is wasting memory and might cause issues with the screen. Ideally, I want to switch between both classes inherited from the same print class in the middle of my program.

Comment: Why are you deriving the `display` class from `Print` at all?    There are plenty of ways of displaying information that don't involve printing.

Comment: `Print` is just a class that has helper functions, for example to convert integer to chars, then it calls my write function

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a single class that can write to both - buffer and screen, then you violate single responsibility rule.

This can be solved with design patterns (visitor, maybe decorator).
Another option would be to use composition instead of inheritance - however, you said that you don't want create separate instances for both printing options. In this case another option would be to use strategy pattern - you could provide methods to set appropriate printing/writing strategy and swap it in runtime whenever you need that.

Comment: By single responsibility rule, do you mean have `displayDirect` inherit from `Print`, then have `display` inherit from `displayDirect` and `Print`?

Comment: Not really. You want to be able to put data to the buffer or to the screen. Although those two tasks seem similar, they are actually quite different and shouldn't be mixed. Similarly you shouldn't handle writing to database and sending data, e.g. using some REST API in the same class. You should consider different approach and inheritance does not seem to be a good solution here.

Answer (score -1):

> Ideally, I want to switch between both classes inherited from the same print class in the middle of my program.

You can create a wrapper class that also implements `Print` and allows you to switch out the underlying implementation:

```cpp
class DelegatedPrint : public Print {

  public:

    delegate_to(Print *wrapped) {
      wrapped_ = wrapped;
    }

  private:

    Print *wrapped_ = nullptr;

    size_t write(uint8_t c) override {
      if (wrapped_) {
        return wrapped_->write(c);
      } else {
        return 0; // Or report error. Or just crash. Up to you.
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: I do not want to create/instantiate both classes in the process

Comment: You want to use them but not instantiate them? That's impossible. You can always delete one before creating the other, if memory consumption is really an issue here.

Comment: Ok, I did not think of that, but maybe I should phrase it another way, I want to keep the display variables while switching, sorry for the misunderstanding